Arduino: How can I set a servo to an angle based on incoming data on COM 3?
I've buildt a box that contains an arduino and a servo motor. The servo should turn based on how much the airspeed is(speedometer). I also have a program that gets the flight sims UDP data and sends it to COM 3. It looks like this:CONDORUDP2COM (34,83 knots)
But I have no idea wether it sends HEX or DEC values and how to convert it.
Any ideas?
Thank you very much!
Kind regards, Jannik
After a bit of trying I ended up with this:
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servoMotor;  

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  servoMotor.attach(3); 
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) { 
    int speed = Serial.parseInt();

    servoMotor.write(speed);
    }
  }
}


Sadly it doesn't work
I thought it would set the servo to the angle based on how fast the airspeed is.
